# Whats wrong with my datetime.strptime format?

Tags: python, python-datetime

With this function:

```
timestamp = datetime.strptime(date_str, date_fmt)
```

I am getting this error:

> ValueError: time data 'Sun, 28 Oct 2018 07:33:13 -0400 (EDT)' does not
>   match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)'

```
Sun, 28 Oct 2018 07:33:13 -0400 (EDT)
%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)
```

I've [looked over it a dozen times](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

My Python Version:

```
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jul 23 2018, 20:24:19)
```

Comment: it works with `(UTC)`. Is EDT a valid zone?

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/edt - Does Python not recognize it for some reason?

Comment: my regex match pattern is `('(?P<a>mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun),\\s+(?P<d>3[0-1]|[1-2]\\d|0[1-9]|[1-9]| '
 '[1-9])\\s+(?P<b>jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\\s+(?P<Y>\\d\\d\\d\\d)\\s+(?P<H>2[0-3]|[0-1]\\d|\\d):(?P<M>[0-5]\\d|\\d):(?P<S>6[0-1]|[0-5]\\d|\\d)\\s+(?P<z>[+-]\\d\\d[0-5]\\d)\\s+\\((?P<Z>paris\\,\\ '
 'madrid\\ \\(heure\\ d\\\x92\\ét\\é\\)|paris\\,\\ madrid|utc|gmt)\\)')` it depends on the current TZ yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no support for `%Z` on input for anything other than your *current timezone*. Only the strings in the [`time.tzname` tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.tzname) plus `'UTC'` and `'GMT'` will ever be recognised:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import time
>>> time.tzname
('GMT', 'BST')
>>> sample = 'Sun, 28 Oct 2018 07:33:13 -0400 (EDT)'
>>> datetime.strptime(sample.replace('EDT', time.tzname[0]), '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)')
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 7, 33, 13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000), 'GMT'))
>>> datetime.strptime(sample.replace('EDT', time.tzname[1]), '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)')
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 7, 33, 13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000), 'BST'))
```

Even if you use a 'known' timezone name in your input, the name is ignored unless there is also an timezone offset (`%z`) in the input; with a `%z` offset it is used only to set the `name` argument of the [`datetime.timezone()` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone) that's constructed from the `%z` offset.

This behaviour is, unfortunately, not clearly documented, see Python issues [#22377](https://bugs.python.org/issue22377) and [#22426](https://bugs.python.org/issue22426). The documentation may seem to *imply* that `EST` would be an acceptable value for `%Z` to parse, but that section of the documentation only shows `datetime.strftime()` string outputs, not acceptable `datetime.strptime()` string inputs.

Since you also have the offset from UTC in the string (the `-0400` part), just remove the timezone name from your input and don't bother trying to parse it:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(sample.rpartition(' ')[0], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 7, 33, 13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)))
```

I used [`str.rpartition()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) here to remove everything starting at the last space, but it depends on what kind of inputs that you have how to best remove the timezone name part in your application. Without it, the `(%Z)` section is not needed and you get a correct `datetime` object.

When debugging `datetime.strptime()` issues, you want to *compartmentalise* the issue. You can bisect the input and template parts to see where the issue lies, or try out the different components one by one. It could be a single directive that causes the issue, or multiple, so I usually go for single-step removing of directives until one works.

---

For those interested in the nitty gritty details of how `datetime.strptime()` works, you can step into the call with a debugger as the implementation [uses a pure Python module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/_strptime.py). For `datetime.strptime()`, the entry point is [`_strptime._strptime_datetime()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1bf672f53a83c471e6fc4599d2d5149fd6842ff2/Lib/_strptime.py#L574-L588), and the `%Z` parameter matching pattern is generated by [this little loop](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1bf672f53a83c471e6fc4599d2d5149fd6842ff2/Lib/_strptime.py#L219-L220), where `self.locale_time.timezone` is a 2-value tuple of frozensets with 3-letter strings, which was set by the [`LocaleTime.__calc_timezone()` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1bf672f53a83c471e6fc4599d2d5149fd6842ff2/Lib/_strptime.py#L161-L176).

Comment: I did not realize this. Good call I'll just shave it off of the string if it is there, thank you.

Comment: So, if it doesn't support non-local timezones, is `UTC` a built-in exception?

Comment: @AdamStarrh: yes, the string 'UTC' also works for `%Z`. `%Z` matches a very limited set of strings.